# Which one is gramatically correct?

Tags: verb-usage

Which one is correct: "Don't wait for us. We ***aren't swimming/aren't going to swim*** today, we're tired.

Comment: We aren't going swimming today .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct but, in a realistic situation, neither is natural. The reason for this is that, for most people, they have to go somewhere- for example, a beach or a swimming pool, in order to swim. So most English speakers would think of the activity as **go/going swimming**, or **go/going for a swim**. In the same way, one might **go to the cinema** or **go out for a meal**. The going is an important part of the activity.

Putting that idea into your sentence, you get:

> Don't wait for us: we aren't going swimming today.
>   Don't wait for us: we aren't going to go swimming today.
>   Don't wait for us: we aren't going for a swim today.
>   Don't wait for us: we aren't going to go for a swim today.

The **don't wait for us** part of the sentence lends weight to the idea that the group of people in this particular situation would have to go somewhere to go swimming.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's an exhaustive answer, and very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

They're both correct but mean two different things. "We aren't swimming today" = we haven't swum and won't swim today. "We aren't going to swim" = we may have swum (or may not have) but, regardless, we won't swim later today.